# How to handle a change in interface subclasses?

Tags: java, api, design-patterns, inheritance, interface

Assume an initial scenario, following which I would be the modified problematic case.

```
interface Logger {
    log() { } 
} 

class LogFile extends Logger {
     log()  { // log to file }
}

class LogDB extends Logger {
     log() { // insert log into DB   } 
}
```

Now LogDB changes into something like:

```
class LogDB {
    logMySQL() { };
    logMongo() { };
}
```

How can this change be incorporated into LogDB while I still want it to fit into Logger interface  ?

Comment: Do you want to log each statement into both databases, or be able to selectively log to one or the other.  If the latter, do you want to make that choice when you start up the program, or at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `LogDB` needs to implement `Log`, but must also do some customized logging, add a function that does the generic logging activity, as required by the interface, and call it from each customized version (or vice-versa, depending on your needs):

```
public void log()  {
   //Common logging stuff here
}
public void logDB()  {
   //Database-specific logging here...
   log();
}
public void logMongo()  {
   //Mongo-specific logging here...
   log();
}
```

But as stated by @kocko, you seem to be mashing two types of logging into one object, which is why you're asking the question in the first place. Split it up as he suggests, then you won't have this problem to begin with.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's better to make two subclasses of the `LogDB` class - one for dealing with MongoDB and one for MySQL.

```
class LogMongoDB extends LogDB {
    @Override
    log() {
       //persist the log in MongoDB
    }
}

class LogMySQL extends LogDB {
    @Override
    log() {
       //persist the log in MySQL
    }    
}
```

Comment: your answer also deserves accept, but i accepted answer of aliteralmind as his points/score on stack overflow are lesser than yours. There is a serious tie between both of you :)

Comment: I've answered your question, but it's based on a flawed design. @kocko's answer fixes your design, and renders both your question and my answer moot. Nice of you to support me, though.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it differently, **not with inheritance**, but with **composition**.

```
interface Logger {
    log(String message) { } 
} 

class LogFile extends Logger {
     public LogFile(File file) {}
     log(String message)  { /* log to file */ }
}

class LogDB extends Logger {
     private DBLogConf dbConf;
     private DBAbstractionLayer dbal;
     public LogDB(IDBLogConf dbConf, IDBAbstractionLayer dbal) {
         this.dbConf = dbConf;
         this.dbal = dbal;
     }
     log(String message) { 
         List<String> fields = new ArrayList<String>();
         fields.add(dbConf.getLogField());

         List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
         fields.add(message);

         dbal.insert(dbConf.getContainer(), fields, values);
     } 
}

interface IDBLogConf {
    public String getContainer(); // table or document
    public String getLogField();
}

class DBLogConf implements IDBLogConf { /* ... */ }

interface IDBAbstractionLayer {
    public void insert(String container, List<String> fields, List<String> values) {
        // ...
    }

    // other methods
}

class JDBCAbstractionLayer implements IDBAbstractionLayer {
    private Connection conn;
    public JDBCAbstractionLayer(Connection conn) {
        this.conn = conn;
    }

    public function insert(...) { /* ... */}
}

abstract class NoSQLAbstractionLayer implements IDBAbstractionLayer {
    // ...
}

class MongoAbstractionLayer extends NoSQLAbstractionLayer {
    // ...
}
```

Putting this all toghether:

```
IDBConf dbConf = new DBConf('log_table', 'details');
IDBAbstractionLayer dbal = new JDBCAbstractionLayer(/* some JDBC connection, */);

Logger dbLogger = new LogDb(dbConf, dbal);
dbLogger.log("Something");

Logger fileLlogger = new LogFile(new File('/var/log/my_log'));
fileLogger.log("Something");
```

However this seems more complex than the above examples, this implementation does not violate SRP and avoids code duplication.